# If $A$ is a square matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-equations

If $A$ is a square matrix, and $A=A^2$, then what would the possible values of $|A|$?

I've tried to calculate it through basic mathematics, however I feel it's not appropriate...
$$A=A^2$$
$$A-A^2=0$$
$$A=0 \text {  or } A=1$$
So $A$ will be a zero matrix or identity matrix.
Hence $|A|$ will be $0$ & $1$ respectively.

But I doubt if we can perform such operations in case of matrices...
Also, I feel there may be more possible solutions, rather than 0 or unity.
Please Guide Accordingly.

Comment: From $A-A^2=0$ you can conclude that $A(I-A)=0$, by distributivity. However, for matrix multiplication, $AB=0$ *does not* imply that $A=0$ or $B=0$. For instance,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\, .
$$

Comment: You're close. The product of the determinants is the determinant of the products. So $det(A)=det(A)^2$.  So $det(A)=0 or 1$. That means $A$ can be any matrix with determinant of 1 or 0.

Comment: @TurlocTheRed It definitely does _not_ mean that $A$ can be any matrix with determinant 0 or 1.

Comment: In fact, if you assume invertibility, then $A(A^{-1}y)=A^2(A^{-1}y)$, so $Ay=y$. Hence the identity is the only matrix with $A=A^2$ that doesn't have $|A|=0$.

Comment: @Joe Why mix $y$ into this? We simply have $$A=A^2\\A^{-1}\cdot A=A^{-1}\cdot A^2\\I=A$$

Comment: @Arthur, great point. I don't know, that was just the first thought that came into my head when I thought about which invertible matrices satisfied the constraint. I didn't spend time trying to make it any more elegant, but yours is.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that $|A|$ is the determinant of the matrix $A$

If $A=A^2$ then what can you say about $|A|$ and $|A^2|$ ?

Also remember that for any two square matrices of the same size A and B we have :
$|AB| = |A||B|$

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In general, $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, so $\det(A^2)=\det(A)^2$. We are given that $A^2=A$, so $\det(A)=\det(A)^2$, which implies that $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=1$. As Arthur mentions in the comments, you need to be careful about the logic: what we have proven is

> For all square matrices $A$, if $A^2=A$ then $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=1$.

This is *not* the same as saying that

> For all square matrices $A$, if $\det(A)=0$ or $\det(A)=1$, then $A^2=A$.

Your argument is not correct because from $A-A^2=0$ you cannot infer that $A$ is the zero matrix or the identity matrix. You *can* infer from $A-A^2=0$ that $A(I-A)=0$, by distributivity; however, there are many matrices that satisfy this equation which are not the zero matrix or the identity matrix, e.g. $\begin{bmatrix}3 & -6 \\ 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}$. This shows that, for matrix multiplication, $AB=0$ does not imply that $A=0$ or $B=0$. (In the language of abstract algebra, we can say that the ring of $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb R$ contains nontrivial zero divisors, for $n>1$.)